# Solve system of ODEs for steady state symbolically

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I can successfully solve a linear system of ODEs describing chemical reactions by first using DSolveValue to find the general solution and then taking the limit to infinity to find the steady state solution.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
eqns = {
    X'[t] == P - (k1 + k2) X[t] + A k1 X[t],
    Y'[t] == k1 X[t] - A k1 X[t] - k3 Y[t],
    X[0] == 0,
    Y[0] == 0
}
s = Assuming[
    k0 > 0 && k1 > 0 && k2 > 0 && k3 > 0 && P > 0 && A >= 0 && A < 1, 
    Limit[
        DSolveValue[eqns,{X[t], Y[t]}, t], t -> \[Infinity]
    ]
]
```

This has the solution
$$\left\{\frac{P}{-A \text{k1}+\text{k1}+\text{k2}},\frac{(A-1) \text{k1} P}{\text{k3} ((A-1) \text{k1}-\text{k2})}\right\}$$

Does mathematica provide a better/builtin way of doing this? For example by using [eigenvalue method](https://yutsumura.com/solving-a-system-of-differential-equation-by-finding-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors/) to find the steady solution directly?

Comment: Could just set the derivatives to zero and solve for `{X,Y}`: `In[4]:= equil = {P - (k1 + k2) xx + A k1 xx, 
   k1 xx - A k1 xx - k3 yy};
Solve[equil == 0, {xx, yy}]

Out[5]= {{xx -> -(P/(-k1 + A k1 - k2)), 
  yy -> ((-k1 + A k1) P)/((-k1 + A k1 - k2) k3)}}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes that’s very clean approach, because this defines the steady state solution I can just treat them as standard equations that are solved for zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give the equilibrium, without checking convergence as `t -> Infinity`:

```
rhs = {X'[t], Y'[t]} /. 
   First@Solve[eqns, {X'[t], Y'[t]}, {X[0], Y[0]}];

Solve[rhs == 0, {X[t], Y[t]}]
(*
  {{X[t] -> -(P/(-k1 + A k1 - k2)), 
    Y[t] -> ((-k1 + A k1) P)/((-k1 + A k1 - k2) k3)}}
*)
```

Here's way to get the convergence criteria:

```
Reduce[
 Thread[
  Eigenvalues[
   CoefficientArrays[rhs, {X[t], Y[t]}][[2]]
   ] < 0
  ],
 {A, k1, k2, k3}
 ]
(*  (A | k1) \[Element] Reals && k2 > -k1 + A k1 && k3 > 0  *)
```

Comment: Getting the convergence criteria is very useful! Thanks

Comment: @DanielFarrell You're welcome, and thank you for the accept.  It just occurred to me I was assuming everything was real (incl. the eigenvalues).  If complex eigenvalues are possible, you could take the real part of the eigenvalues: `Reduce[
 Flatten@{ {A, k1, k2, k3} \[Element] Reals, Thread[ 0 > Re@Eigenvalues[ CoefficientArrays[rhs, {X[t], Y[t]}][[2]] ]] }, {A, k1, k2, k3}]` -- it comes out the same in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is not an ecological model, my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo) could be useful.

```
(* load package *)
<< EcoEvo`;

(* define model *)
SetModel[{
  Aux[X] -> {Equation :> P - (k1 + k2) X[t] + A k1 X[t]}, 
  Aux[Y] -> {Equation :> k1 X[t] - A k1 X[t] - k3 Y[t]},
  Assumptions -> {k0 > 0, k1 > 0, k2 > 0, k3 > 0, 0 <= A < 1}
}]

(* find equilibria *)
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
(* {{X -> -(P/(-k1 + A k1 - k2)),
  Y -> ((-k1 + A k1) P)/((-k1 + A k1 - k2) k3)}} *)

(* check stability *)
EcoStableQ[eq[[1]]]
```

[image: stability conditions]

Based on your assumptions, you will find that the equilibrium is always stable:

```
Simplify[EcoStableQ[eq[[1]]]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: An interesting package. I’m just getting started with Mathematica so I picked the other answer. But this looks useful for when I actually understand what I’m doing!

Comment: Thanks, feel free to hit me up if you try it and have questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial approach also provides the conditions for convergence

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {X'[t] == P - (k1 + k2) X[t] + A k1 X[t], 
   Y'[t] == k1 X[t] - A k1 X[t] - k3 Y[t], X[0] == 0, Y[0] == 0};

sol = DSolve[eqns, {X, Y}, t][[1]];
```

Verifying the solution

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Using [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) to find the steady state also provides the conditions for convergence

```
ss = Limit[{X[t], Y[t]} /. sol, t -> Infinity]
```

[image]

```
cond = (And @@ (Last /@ ss)) // Simplify

(* P ∈ Reals && A k1 + k3 < k1 + k2 && k1 + k2 > A k1 && k3 > 0 *)
```

For your initially specified conditions, the additional requirement is

```
Simplify[cond, 
 k0 > 0 && k1 > 0 && k2 > 0 && k3 > 0 && P > 0 && A >= 0 && A < 1]

(* A k1 + k3 < k1 + k2 *)
```

Comment: That’s true, my original code seems to take much longer. It’s very useful to see how you have manipulated the result here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the system is stable

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
eqns = {X'[t] - P + (k1 + k2) X[t] + A k1 X[t], Y'[t] - k1 X[t] + A k1 X[t] + k3 Y[t]};
teqns = LaplaceTransform[eqns, t, s]
sols = Solve[teqns == 0, {LaplaceTransform[X[t], t, s], LaplaceTransform[Y[t], t, s]}][[1]]
Limit[s {LaplaceTransform[X[t], t, s], LaplaceTransform[Y[t], t, s]} /. sols, {s -> 0}]
```